# Web API authorization for multiple external websites

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-web-api, authorization

There is a requirement to have a common web api application to service 3 different MVC web applications. These client web applications have their own databases and own authentication implementations. How do we configure the web api application to provide access to a set of APIs to web app 1 alone and deny to all other web apps, similarly for web app 2 and so on? In other words, is there a way to 'register' each web app with the web api service and also build in a mechanism through which the web app is only allowed access to a set of endpoints? Thanks for all the help..

Answer (score 1):

There are a handful of ways of solving this

- Host [multiple WebAPI servers in a single process](http://www.aaron-powell.com/posts/2014-12-04-multiple-webapi-single-process.html) to effectively meet your requirement while making your project easier to organize
- Use [Authentication and Authorization filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-filters) to customize how requests are accepted, denied, and routed
- Using a router and/or switch at the hardware level, create a blacklist/whitelist combined with a reverse proxy (beware of MAC spoofing, etc, with this solution)
- Use dependency injection to add abstraction to the process and to remove the ability to specify a custom endpoint in an unintended manner programmatically; this solution will only work if you control the client code, however

From the sound of it, the issue you're describing doesn't seem like one regarding the visibility of the endpoints, but of the access control to leverage them. If I'm wrong, please let me know in a comment and I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your response @william and also for the number of options provided. Yes you are right. It is more about access than visibility. I have updated the question to reflect that. I am interested in exploring option 2 in your comment. Is there a way to dynamically create and assign authorization filters to a set of endpoints in the web api service based on external web app registrations, maybe something that could be done during web-api app start?